# why the XML validator gives failed to read error about the existing xds include file

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following errors reported in my (scorm 2004) xml file, what is causing this error since the referenced include file imsss_v1p0util.xsd is present in the same folder.

row 8 has this tag:
    < xs:include schemaLocation = "imsss_v1p0util.xsd"/ >

parser output:

```
Validating the XML for Wellformedness
The XML is Well-formed
Validating the XML against the Controlling Documents
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0seqrule.xsd'. line: 8, col: 56
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0objective.xsd'. line: 9, col: 58
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0delivery.xsd'. line: 10, col: 57
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0random.xsd'. line: 11, col: 55
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0rollup.xsd'. line: 12, col: 55
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0control.xsd'. line: 13, col: 56
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0limit.xsd'. line: 14, col: 54
ERROR: src-include.0: Failed to read included schema document 'imsss_v1p0auxresource.xsd'. line: 15, col: 60
ERROR: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'controlModeType' to a(n) type definition component. line: 28, col:
```

test kit tool is Sharable Content Object Reference Model (SCORM ®) 2004 3rd Edition

Answer (score 1):

The XML headers for a SCORM manifest can be a bit tricky to get right. If you can post the entire manifest (or at least the header), I might be able to help you spot the error. Alternatively, there are some templates available at http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/xml-schema-definition-files/ that you can simply copy and paste.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

None of those error messages mention the imsss_v1p0util.xsd file. If you look inside of imsss_v1p0util.xsd, I bet you'll find that it includes the others. You probably want those others to be in the same directory as imsss_v1p0util.xsd.

Comment: I am afraid this has something to do with a spacebar in folder name of customer running validation as its working OK with my own test machine